# Mac Pro - some keys in default shift mode

Tags: keyboard, mac-pro

My Mac Pro keyboard was working fine few minutes ago, but some keys are typing in shift mode now. What should I do to fix it?

I thought of restarting the laptop but suddenly realised I wont be able to log in.

A-Z in non-caps mode appear like:

`aBCdefghijklMNopqrstuVwXyZ`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, my keyboard started working all fine after I connected my laptop to keyboard. I still don't know what was the reason for this.